# Create a numeric-type calculated field using concatenation, in MS-Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a column `ProjectYear` and a column `ProjectNumber`; both are numbers. I created a calculated column (`[ProjectYear] & "" & [ProjectNumber]`) which concatenates the two. For instance, *2015* and *123* gives *2015123*.

The issue is that the resulting type of that calculated columns is *Short Text*, and when I create a query to join to another table which has that column in, but as a numeric type, I get a `type mismatch` error.

How can I make the calculated column have a numeric type?

I tried `CInt([ProjectYear] & "" & [ProjectNumber])`, but that it is not allowed.

Comment: what about `[ProjectYear] *1000 + [ProjectNumber]`

Comment: That will not work because project number are no only 3 digits they can be   more that 3 or less

Comment: Any time you do a concatenate it becomes a txt field, You'll have to convert it to a number using cint([projectyear] & [projectNumber])  (take out the "") or convert the number field in the other table to a string using cstr()

Comment: access does not see CInt as a valid expression inside the design table

Comment: use a custom public function to turn two variable you pass into it a concatenated interger value.

Comment: how can I do that custom public function?

Comment: have you tried it without the "" just as [ProjectYear] & [ProjectNumber]

Comment: Are you writing your query, or dragging over query wizzard?  some functions are only aviable when you write the query.  may be `cint` case

Comment: in the table design of your calucluted field (which is evil.) what is the result type you have specified?

Comment: I tried [ProjectYear] & [ProjectNumber] but it didnt work

Comment: same error? testing i ran shows any of these suggestions should work (expect CInt, HansUp has that one right). can you post your entire query?

Comment: This question is not about a query.  It is about a calculated field in table design --- a feature which MS added to the ACCDB database format in Access 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A calculated field expression can only use a limited set of functions.  `CInt()` is not supported, but `Int()` is.

I tested this one in Access 2010, with *Long Integer* for the calculated field's *Result Type* property, and it does what I think you want ...

```vb
Int([ProjectYear] & [ProjectNumber])
```

Note I believe you are asking about a calculated field in table design, such as this ...

[image]

Also note that a calculated field can not be indexed.  That has performance implications when you use that field in a join to another table --- although the datatypes can be compatible, it can't take advantage of indexed retrieval.